# Is there a way place table cells within div or workaround

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, getelementbyid

I have a page using a table layout.  It has three columns  I would like to have links in the first (left most) column which change the contents of the two columns to the right using Javascript.

Tried putting the two `table` cells in a `div` or `span` element but that does not seem to be valid HTML

I know you are allowed to put a div or span inside one cell.  However, I'd like to use two cells as a sort of "pane" to display what is behind links.  And starting out, given what needs to be shown, I'd prefer two separate cells, not one double cell.

Going to table-less layout is not an option as this is a legacy site.

Can anyone suggest a workaround to create a two column pane to display content when a link gets clicked?

html

```
<table
    <tr>
        <td>StartContent1</td>
        <td>StartContent2</td>
        <td>StartContent3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="loadPane();">Link</a>
        </td>
        <span id="pane">
            <td>StartContent4</td>
            <td>StartContent5</td>
        </span>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
function loadPane() {
    document.getElementById('pane').innerHTML= "<td colspan=2>Two columns worth of expanded content</td>;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have anything besides `<td>` and `<th>` elements inside a table row.

Try something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="loadPane();">Link</a>
    </td>
    <td id="pane">StartContent4</td>
    <td id="paneHide">StartContent5</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
var pane = document.getElementById('pane');
pane.innerHTML = 'Two columns worth of expanded content';
pane.setAttribute('colspan','2');
var paneHide = document.getElementById('paneHide');
paneHide.parentNode.removeChild(paneHide);
```

Comment: Do I still use document.getElementById('pane').innerHTML = pane; to set values on page?

Comment: Got it to insert new text and also hide old text but it does not extend new text over two columns ie pane.colspan=2  Since I have color background in the cells, I can see the two cells are still distinct.

Comment: You need to use setAttribute method to modify colspan attribute. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: OK.  Got it to work in jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/afZ4f/   Still not working in my code but I must have some other error.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with nested tables. Think of an outer table where you put a link in the left column. In the right column of the outer table you put a div. In side this div lives the inner table with 2 columns, which gets replaced with a new inner table with one column once you click the link.

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/k92pK/) can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/k92pK/

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table id='outerTable'>
            <tr>
                <td>StartContent1</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>StartContent2</td>
                            <td>StartContent3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="loadPane();">Link</a></td>
                <td>
                    <div id='pane'>
                        <table id='innerTable'>
                            <tr>
                                <td>StartContent4</td>
                                <td>StartContent5</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src='main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
function loadPane() {
    var pane = document.getElementById('pane')
    pane.innerHTML= '<table id="newInnerTable"><tr><td>Two columns worth of expanded content</td></tr></table>';
};
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is that the the two columns at page load will not have identical widths. This is because there will be separate table in each row. I think it is better to modify the cells separately.